# Is it possible to delete IP destination cache from C#?

Tags: c#, windows, networking

We have a problem which can be fixed by performing **`netsh interface ip delete destinationcache`** from command line (while running as administrator).

**Is it possible to delete this IP destinationcache or invoke some similar functionality e.g. via WMI, but without requiring elevation?**

(invoking netsh via `Process.Start` will require elevation so it is not an option)

Comment: If you could, wouldn't that defeat the purpose of elevation in the first place?

Comment: I do not know if it is netsh or something deeper down in Windows which is triggering the elevation requirement so I thought it would not hurt to ask.